# Cannot run google chrome installed by one user by another user

Tags: xubuntu, google-chrome

I have created two user accounts say `pragnesh` and `pintu`. Both users are admin users.

I have installed `google-chrome` from pintu but I can't run the application in pragnesh account.

I am running Xubuntu 14.04 LTS version.

Permissions for `google-chrome`:

```
pintu@pragnesh-pc:~$ which google-chrome
/usr/bin/google-chrome
```

`pintu@pragnesh-pc:/usr/bin$ ls -l google-chrome` command shows output below:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Apr 26 13:14 google-chrome -> /etc/alternatives/google-chrome
```

Comment: @ErkinAlpGüney, user2(pintu) have permission `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Apr 26 13:14 google-chrome -> /etc/alternatives/google-chrome`

Comment: Can you post the results of `update-alternatives --list google-chrome`?

Comment: @ErkinAlpGüney, `pintu@pragnesh-pc:~$ update-alternatives --list google-chrome
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable`

Comment: Check whether profile files are correctly owned and have the right permissions.

Comment: Did you install chrome from `apt` ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to install *chrome browser*:

1. using *.deb* packages, or via
2. Ubuntu ppa repository

In the first case where you actually install it to *make* it accessible by all users will be determined by you, and in the second case *Ubuntu packaging* system will install for all users by default.

Multi-user applications are placed in the `/usr` directory with system wide config files in `/etc`, while personal or user specific apps are placed in the `/home` directory of the particular *user*. User specific configurations will be in the `/home/username/.config` folder.